# Jquery/css not selector does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, negation

I'm trying to exclude one block from my jquery selection.

I have the following html structure:

```
<div id="center">
    ...
    <div id="menu>
        <!-- menu -->
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Now I want to select all elements from #center except for the menu.
That's why my jquery look like this:

```
$("#center").not("#menu")....
```

But this seems to select exactly the same as

```
$("#center")....
```

I also tried

```
$("#center:not(#menu)")....
```

And this also gave me the same result. So how can I select all elements from a div without a certain div?

Comment: Well, an element with the ID `center` can't possibly also have the ID `menu`.

Comment: I'd be curious to know why you need to select all descendants except one. Seems like you may be taking a wrong approach.

Comment: @Danny Saying they give exactly the same result as selecting the single DIV using `$('#center')` seems pretty explicit to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to select other divs that are siblings of `#menu` and are child of `#center`:

```
$("#center> *").not("#menu");
```

**[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nz9cf/11/)**

For all contents:

```
$("#center *").not("#menu");
```

**[working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nz9cf/13/)**

Answer (score 1):

seems like you should be doing something like

```
$("#center").children().not("#menu");
```

Answer (score 0):

Selects all with id='center' which doesn't have id='menu'

```
$("#center").not("#menu")
```

logically doesn't make much sense.

You should use

```
$("#center *").not("#menu");
```

instead which selects all elements inside center which don't have id=menu.

Comment: This would select every descendant element, and is therefore not terribly efficient.

Comment: isn't it a case to select all descendant elements?

Comment: Just the children of `#center`, as I understand it.

Comment: I understood that @genz is asking for all but it can be my mistake. Anyway I think that the question was already well answered :)